# Meaning of l = (2 << 2 | 3 << 2) in Python

Tags: python

I m not sure what the above expression means in Python. Did some Google search but still nothing. The value of l is 12.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Do you know what the individual operators mean?

Comment: bitwise operations, read about them.

Comment: @user3001408 because these are explained on any list of Python operators (e.g. first Google hit: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm)?

Answer (score 8):

They are bit-wise operations. ([Binary bitwise operations](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations), [Shifting operations](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#shifting-operations))

If you represent the numbers in binary, it would be easier to understand.

```
>>> bin(2)
'0b10'
>>> bin(3)
'0b11'
>>> bin(2 << 2)  # << : Shift left
'0b1000'
>>> bin(3 << 2)
'0b1100'
>>> bin(2 << 2 | 3 << 2)
'0b1100'

>>> int('1100', 2)
12
```

Comment: 2 << 3 is not in the question.

Comment: @recursive, Thank you for giving me chance to correct it. Fixed it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This is simply bit shift operators and binary OR, meaning

```
2 << 2 # shift 2 which is 0b00010 left by two positions

3 << 2 # shift 3 which is 0b00011 left by two positions

(2 << 2 | 3 << 2) take OR of these values
```

Comment: You could add something about *operator priority* as well.